# NSA CAE/IAE courses

Tags: professional-education

Is there any list of specific courses that the NSA suggests to be taken at the schools that they have designated CAE/IAE? I have a general knowledge of what courses I should take, but I still want to see a list of suggestions from the NSA (for B.S, M.S, and PhD).

Answer (score 4):

I think the NSA leaves the choice of classes to the institution. They merely approve or reject a presented curriculum. See [IA Courseware Evaluation Program](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/academic_outreach/iace_program/index.shtml). Section 5 of [NSTISSI No. 4011](http://www.cnss.gov/Assets/pdf/nstissi_4011.pdf)